# Job queue for PHP and C# scripts

Tags: c#, php, rabbitmq, gearman

I'm looking for best solution to run tasks (performed by C# and PHP scripts) which are sharing same dataset. Execution time of this script varies from 5 min - 10 min. Scripts are placed on different servers and return results to main server.

I need to run PHP script right after C# script gets the job done. Right now, I might use one PHP script on main server with `file_get_contents()` and call another PHP script that uses `exec()` to run **.exe** and waits for response.

After that I'll run second PHP task script. I saw multiple solutions for this, like `Gearman` and `RabbitMQ`.

I would like to know which solution is best for this kind of simple problem, and avoid using `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ, Gearman and other queueing solutions won't prevent you fro using `file_get_contents()`. They will allow you to write that code so that it runs somewhere else... a separate process, or even on a different server. But your code is still going to do what it needs to do, to read a file and execute another process.

Comment: It's not possible somehow to wait for workers to get their job done? I would check in client script each 30 seconds if worker has finished his job and then run second job?

Comment: i don't understand the question. can you clarify what you're asking and what you are trying to accomplish, in the original question?

Comment: Yes. I have two scripts on different servers using same dataset to complete task. I want to run first script, then wait it to finish, then run second one. Also, I would like to avoid open connection (for 10 minutes) using `file_get_content()`.